# How to Set a Fixed ID to the SharePoint WebPart Div?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I've created an empty visual webpart in sharepoint 2010 and it's rendered like this:

width="100%" id="WebPartctl00_m_g_2c05f3a9_2b15_466c_bd32_479ac15c19c6" haspers="false"

webpartid2="2c05f3a9-2b15-466c-bd32-479ac15c19c6" webpartid="7cc8033b-a2eb-4cd8-90d8-28fb3bc52112">

Contents here

As can be seen, SharePoint renders 2 nested divs with auto generated ids.

How is it possible to set a fixed id to either of these divs?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible. Why do you need it? If you need it for styling, just emit your contents encapsulated inside a custom div from the web Part.

Alternatively, if you want the style to be applied on all web Parts , override the sharepoint styles which are applied on all web parts.

Check out this useful CSS guide for sharepoint:
http://www.heathersolomon.com/content/sp07cssreference.htm

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the GUID in the div is a reference to how the web parts are stored in the webpartmanager in asp.net.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8dcy47h%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

This is different for each placement of the webpart, so I'm not sure that hard coding the GUID is a good idea, or even possible.